# Creating switch case onClickListener for TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, onclicklistener

I've just started out in Java programming and am having a bit of trouble implementing an OnClickListener switch case for my clickable TextViews. I've managed to make a switch case for menu items, but i'm obviously not understanding it enough to make a more general case.

Here's the bits of my code that are important to it

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
TextView tv, tv1, tv2, tv3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//get textviews
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xval);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yval);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zval);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scalar);
```

And then I setup individual on click listeners for each TextView, e.g.

```
tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do things
            }
        }
    });
```

But i'm trying to set it up so i have a a combined OnClickListener, like:

```
@Override
public boolean onClickListener (View v) {
    switch (tv.findViewById()) {
        case tv:
            //Do things
            return true;
        case tv1:
            //Do things
            return true;
        case tv2:
            //Do things
            return true;
        case tv3:
            //Do things
            return true;

}}
```

I'm aware that code is very wrong, but i can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've already assigned my findViewById so i'm not sure what else to put into the switch!

Thankyou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll provide an alternative answer. First you have to create an `OnClickListener`, which will receive your OnClick events:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.xval:
                    //code
                    break;

                case R.id.yval:
                    //code
                    break;

                case R.id.zval:
                    //code
                    break;

                case R.id.scalar:
                    //code
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    };
```

Then, you have to associate that listener to every `TextView` you have:

```
tv.setOnClickListener(listener);
tv1.setOnClickListener(listener);
tv2.setOnClickListener(listener);
tv3.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Once you click one of the `TextViews`, your `OnclickListener` `onClick()` callback will be called and it will check the `TextView` id you have clicked and run the code accordingly, dependeing on the case.

Answer (score 3):

```
 tv.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv1.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv2.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv3.setOnClickListener(this);

     @Override
        public boolean onClick (View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.xval:
                    //Do things
                    return true;
                case R.id.yval:
                    //Do things
                    return true;
                case R.id.zval:
                    //Do things
                    return true;
                case R.id.scalar:
                    //Do things
                    return true;

        }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one listener, add it to all `TextView`. Switch on the view id, which is a simple `int`

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.xval:
                //Do things
                return true;
            case R.id.yval:
                //Do things
                return true;
            case R.id.zval:
                //Do things
                return true;
            case R.id.scalar:
                //Do things
                return true;
        }
       }
};

tv.setOnClickListener(listener);
tv1.setOnClickListener(listener);
tv2.setOnClickListener(listener);
tv3.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: I'm curious to learn, why did you use "return true;" after each case?  Most times when I see cases, I see "break;" at the end of the case.  Any major advantages or differences to using "return true;"